# how to parsing Json with SwiftyJson from woocommerce api?

Tags: swift3, alamofire, swifty-json

I want to parse JSON using alamofire and swiftyjson

I try get JSON(value) like this

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Authorization": "Basic Y2tfZTA1ZGNmMDkwNTNmODEyMGQwYTMyOGI4YzJkY2QzOTY5MmE5ZDAyNzpjc18zYzZiYWY2NTM0NDhkNDM4ZDM1ZDNmNDY5Nzg5ZGM2Y2VhZGRiZjNl",
        "Accept": "application/json"
    ]

    Alamofire.request("https://woo.demoapp.xyz/wp-json/wc/v2/products?category=15", headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
        debugPrint(response)

        if let json = response.result.value {
            print("JSON: \(json)")

        }

    }
```

here is the JSON data from woocommerce api

```
[
{
    "id": 29,
    "name": "Sunglasses",
    "permalink": "https://woo.demoapp.xyz/product/sunglasses/",
    "description": "<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>\n",
    "images": [
        {
            "id": 17,
            "src": "https://woo.demoapp.xyz/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/sunglasses.jpg",
            "name": "Sunglasses",

        }
    ],
```

The issue is i am not able to populate an array with what I thought would be correct code to parse a JSON file with swiftyJSON in to tableview.

Comment: Please search: [There are many related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswifty-json%5D+parse+json) and learn to read JSON. It's pretty easy: `{}` is dictionary, `[]` is array. All keys are strings. Values in double quotes are `String`, without double quotes are `Int`

Comment: Do you want to populate in a table view? or Simply?

Comment: i have posted the answer please use this code and i also tested the count getting 4.

Comment: @BHAVIKPANCHAL i want to populate in a table view. how to implement?

Comment: can you seen my answer i have posted?

Comment: i have added the table view code please check my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use this type

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
    "Authorization": "Basic Y2tfZTA1ZGNmMDkwNTNmODEyMGQwYTMyOGI4YzJkY2QzOTY5MmE5ZDAyNzpjc18zYzZiYWY2NTM0NDhkNDM4ZDM1ZDNmNDY5Nzg5ZGM2Y2VhZGRiZjNl",
    "Accept": "application/json"
]

Alamofire.request("https://woo.demoapp.xyz/wp-json/wc/v2/products?category=15", headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
    debugPrint(response)

    if let json = response.result.value {
        print("JSON: \(json)")
        let swjson = JSON(response.result.value!)
        print(swjson)
        // callback(swjson,nil)
        var myMutableDictionary = [AnyHashable: Any]()
        myMutableDictionary["myArray"] = swjson

        let sss =   JSON(myMutableDictionary as Any)

        let arrdata =    sss["myArray"].arrayObject

        var productArray = NSArray()

        productArray = arrdata as! [[String:AnyObject]] as NSArray

        print(productArray.count)

        yourtableview.reload()
    }

}
```

//table view method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return productArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomeCell

    let dic = productArray[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
    let name =  dic.object(forKey: "name") as! String

    return cell
}
```

Comment: how to parsing "src" at image ?

Comment: there is one another method for upload image with a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Upload Image With Parameter Using Alamofire

```
let parameters = ["category":"15" as AnyObject]

let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
    "Authorization": "Basic Y2tfZTA1ZGNmMDkwNTNmODEyMGQwYTMyOGI4YzJkY2QzOTY5MmE5ZDAyNzpjc18zYzZiYWY2NTM0NDhkNDM4ZDM1ZDNmNDY5Nzg5ZGM2Y2VhZGRiZjNl",
    "Accept": "application/json"
]

Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

    multipartFormData.append(fileUrl , withName: "image" , fileName: yourfilename + ".yourfiletype", mimeType: "yourfiletype")

    for (key, value) in parameters {
        multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
    }

},to: "https://woo.demoapp.xyz/wp-json/wc/v2/products", method: .post, headers: headers ,
  encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
    switch encodingResult {
    case .success(let upload, _, _):
        upload.response { [weak self] response in
            guard self != nil else {
                return
            }

        }

        upload.responseJSON {  response in

            let responseJSON = response.result.value as! NSDictionary


        }

    case .failure(let encodingError):
        print("error:\(encodingError)")

    }


})
```