# Video upload for webm format in swift using alamofire is it possible?

Tags: macos, swift3

Can I upload a video in "video.webm" format to my server using alamofire in swift 3? This video is saved in a file directory say file://xyz/.
I am actually building a Mac app with video upload feature.

I know this code is not right can anyone guide me

```
Alamofire.upload(
multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
    multipartFormData.append(data, name: "videoFile",
                 fileName: "video1.webm", mimeType: "video/webm"), 
    multipartFormData.append(data1, name: "image1File",
                fileName: "video2.webm", mimeType: "video/webm")
},
to: "https://httpbin.org/post", //URL,
headers: headers,
encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
    switch encodingResult {
    case .success(let upload, _, _):
        upload.responseJSON { response in
            debugPrint(response)
        }
        upload.uploadProgress(closure: { //Get Progress
                progress in
                    print(progress.fractionCompleted)
            })
    case .failure(let encodingError):
        print(encodingError)
    }
})
```

Comment: can you use with this code https://stackoverflow.com/a/46986370/6193340

Comment: does the file stored at disk be uploaded? as in I don't have to convert video to data or anything right? just the url is enough right?

Comment: Url is enough and just enter name withou extention define extention

Comment: seems like its working server side has issues will update once thats sorted