# how to upload Image and data as Multipart in swift Alamofire

Tags: swift, swift3, alamofire, alamofireimage

I am an android guy and I have achieved this in android I need to convert this code into swift now for my ios project, I have tried uploading my the data and the image using Alamofire in ios and I have been struggling since a week if you guys can help me out here.

my data looks like this

```
First String- 
   ---------SWPMCF1Le5z\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"files\"; filename=\"IMG_20171021_192906.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image*\/\/*\r\n\r\n"

"This is my image data in bytes"



Second String  
 ---------SWPMCF1Le5z
        Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"
        Content-Type: application/json

{"thread":{"title":"hh","site_id":177},"comment":{"shift_id":4,"subject":"hh","message":"gt","entered_at":"2017-11-02 10:52:56","priority":"high","author_id":1621,"entities":[],"fields":[],"files":[],"images":[{"filename":"IMG_20171021_192906.jpg"}],"fileData":[{"data":"\/storage\/6535-3331\/DCIM\/Camera\/IMG_20171021_192906.jpg"}]}}
---------SWPMCF1Le5z--
```

Now I need to send this using Alamofire to server but I was getting

```
Error code -1001
```

of which I have no clue.
I tried several ways into Alamofire like using multipart, standard way then I tried standard way of hitting the server in swift with no luck Please if you guys can help me out.
I did the same thing in the android in standard way.
Here is my android code if you guys and figure out.

```
    InputStream fStream = null;
                try {
                    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(http.getOutputStream());
                    for (int i = 0; i < body.length(); i++) {
                        String string = body.optString(i);
//Here I am writing the image data into http outputstream
                        if (string.startsWith("[FILE]")) {
                            File file = new File(string.replace("[FILE]", ""));
                            fStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                            int bufferSize = 1024;
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                            int length;
                            while ((length = fStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                                out.write(buffer, 0, length);
                            }
                            fStream.close();
                        } else {

    //Here I am writing the the first and second string.
                                out.writeBytes(string);
                            }
                        }
                        out.flush();
                        out.close();
                    } catch (ConnectException e) {
                        return null;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return null;
                    }
                    try {
                        if (fStream != null) fStream.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Please guys help me out here and let me know if any more code is need.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this article on Medium: [Alamofire multipart upload](https://medium.com/@hanifsgy/alamofire-multipart-with-parameters-upload-image-from-uiimagepickercontroller-swift-a4abada24ae?source=linkShare-ec24e2bbb2f8-1509609421)

Comment: I have gone through every article which can be found on the internet still not able to figure out.

Comment: Can you show your swift code?

Comment: can you try with this my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46945764/how-to-parsing-json-with-swiftyjson-from-woocommerce-api/46986370#46986370

Comment: yeah I have tried it I dont understand how to send my string as a parameter in multipart if I don't have a key?